# In Operations, what does the Attack/Defense rating actually do?

Tags: battlefield-1

After successfully attacking or defending in Operations mode, the score screen displays an attack/defense rating.

Usually, this comes in the form of XX/XX, where the X represents a number of varying amounts. For example, my team just failed on attack, and the screen said "Attack Rating: -148/33." I've seen a defense rating of 745/38 as well, but I have absolutely no idea what any of this information means.

What is the point of this seemingly pointless rating?

Comment: Only seen speculation up to now on both the official forums and then sites like reddit. At no point have I seen an official dev response either.
I have a feeling its broken and until its fixed they won't say ANYTHING about it at all

Comment: it does feel pretty neat to get 183 out of apparently a possible 27.

Comment: Definitely broken, Were it not for the fact that its pure speculation and theory, I would post an answer explain what the patterns are, but I get the feeling it would not go to well for me. None the less, there are definitly some patterns regarding the cap, number of sectors, and the messages it gives you after a sector is taken

Comment: I hit up EA online support chat for some insight, and the very first thing the representative suggested was [this link](https://forums.battlefield.com/en-us/discussion/53494/attack-defense-rating-in-operations) stating my answer could be found there (it most certainly cannot).  I asked the rep. how its calculated and they said "For attack you have too destroy them completely for good rating & in defense you have to save your troop as much you can." Seems legit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user at [Battlefields Forums](https://forums.battlefield.com/en-us/discussion/41414/operations-attack-rating) says that:

> I think it may be how you as a Player/Team did in attacking/defending. The number on the right I'm thinking is the average a player/Team should be at. The number on the left reflects how you/the Team did. The higher the value on the left compared to the right, the higher the (X) value will be that raises your ending score.

You said that your team failed at attacking thus matches the description above where the number on the lest is really low. You might have done really well at defense on the other hand thus the high defense score. Of course, sometimes it's not that accurate according to a [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/battlefield_one/comments/5b6m76/operation_attackdefense_rating_anyone_know_what/) (the comments may provide useful):

[image]

According to another [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Battlefield/comments/59mv85/bf1_can_somebody_explain_attackdefense_rating_on/), the number on the left is your rating and the number on the right is the standard set by the developers:

> Last time this was asked I said it's probably a way to determine if your team did well compared to a "standard", in this case "27". God knows why, everyone knows 42 is the answer to everything but there you have it.
>
> If your team's K/D, time needed to capture points on attack, time needed to kill off all attackers as defenders, etc.. is better than an average set by the devs, you get a better score multiplier after the round.
>
> You can still lose and get a positive multiplier because of this.
>
> The negative score you sometimes get is probably due to the fact that it's calculated against the defence standard when you are on the attacking force. I'm no programmer though so don't hold it against me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you're not meant to outright win some maps. Instead you're given a score depending on how strong your attack was:

- If your attack was decent but you couldn't get an outright win, you'll have a minus score.
- If your defence was crap but you manage to just barely hold off a loss, you'll get close to zero but positive.

This is not 100% confirmed but just my observations.

Answer (score 0):

This was completely broken in the beta. 
As of final version of the game it seems to be working correctly.

The final result seems to be the total of each sectors' attack/defense rating from both maps.

For example Conquer Hell is two maps, Ballroom Blitz with 4 sectors, and Argonne Forest with 5. That's 9 total, maximum rating is 3 therefore your best operation rating is 27/27.

Comment: This doesn't explain why I've seen ratings of "-687/27" as of a week ago, though.

Comment: @Fluttershy are you sure it was a week ago? I haven't seen any results like that since mid-December patch.